# Show div if {{}} expression returns nothing with ng-show. Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular expression which returns some data

```
    <span class="detail">
        {{details.info}}
    </span>
```

But if the expression doesn't return any data, because there may be none to return in some cases, I want another div to appear. Obviously my approach is incorrect, could someone point me in the right direction?

```
    <span ng-show="!details.info">
        <p class="no">No Data</p>
    </span>
```

Comment: syntax and concept is good, what's the problem ? Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="detail">
    <p ng-if="!details.strategy" class="no">No Data</p>
    {{details.strategy}}
</span>
```

Comment: Ah jeez... I naturally assumed I would need to set class="no" to display:none. But angular takes care of that for you! Cheers Alon, appreciate the response"!